# Cannot emulate Raspberry on QEMU

Tags: raspbian, kernel, terminal, emulation, qemu

I have a problem when I want to emulate a Raspberry on QEMU.
I created a "start.bat" where I put:

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" -drive "file=2020-02-13-raspbian-buster.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw" -redir tcp:2222::22
```

After that,  I launch the cmd console from the folder where there is all the needed files for the emulation.
I put in the console "start.bat" and it shows me that :
[image: What shows the console when I put "start.bat"]

Comment: I afraid we cannot help much with running software/emulation on a MS Windows machine. You may consider to ask on a MS Windows forum to get more qualified answers.

Comment: "Can someone help me on this problem" post text - not illegible images.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining about the "-redir" command line option and from the reference at:

[qemu-system-arm man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/qemu-system-arm/qemu-system-arm.1.en.html)

There does not appear to be any such option.  Try removing this option.